# How to set certain checkbox to disabled based on given array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have an array of comma separated string. This will determined whick checkbox should be disabled.

```
var lbl = "A,C";
```

Then I want to compare it on the checkboxes in the form. The check boxes values are `A`,`B`,`C`,`D`.

Based on the string given, the checkbox which value are `A` and `C` should be disabled.

This is my current script:

```
$('#f_sendTo input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {

    var arr_cek_txt = $(this).val().split('||');   //This is checkboxes value
    var arr_lbl_ext = lbl.split(',');              //this is the string = "A,C"

    var val_lbl_ext;

    $.each(arr_lbl_ext,function(i){


        if(arr_cek_txt[1] == arr_lbl_ext[i]){

            $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }           
    });                 
});
```

Comment: share html mark up as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

Loop thru the checkbox using `each()`. Check the value and if the value is in array, disable the checkbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lbl = "A,C";
  var arr_lbl_ext = lbl.split(','); /* Init this outside each. So that no need to do this every loop*/

  $('#f_sendTo input[type=checkbox]').each(function() {
    var arr_cek_txt = $(this).val(); /* Get the value of checkbox */

    if (arr_lbl_ext.indexOf(arr_cek_txt) == -1) $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    else $(this).prop("disabled", true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="f_sendTo">
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="A"> A <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="B"> B <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="C"> C <br />
  <input type="checkbox" name="cb" value="D"> D <br />
</div>
```